# ios changing depths of views opacity transition

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working on something that will require me to cycle through images and create some sort of fade in and fade out transition between them. I'm used to javascript, so naturally I would want change the depth of the imageview that is going to be faded in. Is there a way to choose which view shows on the top? Or is there a better way of doing what I want to achieve?

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 280.0);


UIImageView *image_one = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
image_one.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_one.png"];
[self.view addSubview:image_one];

UIImageView *image_two = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
image_two.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_two.png"];
[self.view addSubview:image_two];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a view from the view hierarchy, then re-insert it using `[UIView insertSubview:aboveSubview:]` and `[UIView insertSubview:belowSubview:]`.